# Recycle / Stop-Start application pool

Tags: sharepoint-server, application-pool, services

Over the last 2 days I've had a client's sharepoint site just stop working.  There are 2 sharepoints sites running on their server, call them sp1 and sp2.  sp2 had no issues, but when users clicked on a link to sp1, it would just spin, not throwing any indicating error.  Nothing indicated in event logs either.

Recycled sp1 and the site worked, but still slightly sluggish.  Today the sp1 site stopped working again.  This time, recycle did not work, so I had to stop the application pool, wait about a minute, then start it.  Now sp1 is loading as it should and without any sluggishness.

Suffice it to say, I am NOT an sharepoint admin and really, just learning the basics.

1. What is recycling or 'stop/starting' the pool actually doing?
2. Are there logs I can view to see WHY this needed to be done?  Client is asking for a root cause.
3. Is there a way that something can be set up so the client gets notification [email] when the site 'stops working' again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The app pool is the webservices deployed on your iis instance.By refreshing the pool you are fundamentally restarting the application and re-establishing the DB connection(s).
2. You can check the Event Logs from Event Viewer on the servers, Also you can check the ULS Logs( SharePoint) from hive folder `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS` its depend 14 for 2010 or 15 for 2013. If they change the logs path to custom then you can check it from `Central admin > Monitoring > Configure Diagnostic Logging` from here you will see the path.
3. You need a monitoring tool which will monitor the sharepoint i.e SCOM from MSFT. But if the app pool is hang then no body will tell u.

Another thing you should check the App Pool Settings, as best practice it should recycle once a day usually earl AM hours. For root cause you need to check the ULS why it taking too much time. IF user getting the correlation ID then you can search the ULS logs for that correlation ID.

Comment: We actually have SCOM with Sharepoint server 2007, 2012 and foundation 2010.  But even with this, application pool hanging will not alert?

Comment: no it will not but it will if web application is not responding.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you recycle application pool that time the cache and all the services related to that will be reset. So cache will be cleared and some amount of memory will be become free. It will stop the web services and restart it.
2. Check event logs and logs in hive folder
3. You can create a console application and in that you can request the site you want to check whether it is working or not. If you didn't get any response after request the you can send the mail using SMTP. You can add this console application to your windows task scheduler and run it in specific time interval.

Comment: The restart of the web services, thats for that application pool only within SP,  not the IIS service on the server?

Comment: Yes it won't reset IIS service, it is particular to that application pool.